# initial configuration of a switch

Tags: networking, switch, hpe

I have a HPE FF 5940 switch , i have configured an admin user and a management interface (M-GigabitEthernet0/0/0)  and ssh connection to the switch. these are the only configuration i did .

i have connected interface 1/0/1 with a 1GB transceiver 1/0/3 with a 10GB transceiver . this is the configuration :

Interface              Link            Speed          Duplex       Type PVID   Description
XGE1/0/1               UP             1G                 F                  A       1
XGE1/0/2              DOWN       auto             A                  A       1
XGE1/0/3              UP             10G(a)          F(a)              A      1

the problem is that the traffic doesn't flow through the switch  what i mean is i tried pinging host behind the 1GB interface from the host behind the 10GB port , i also tried pinging the M-GigabitEthernet interface from the host connected in 1/0/3 without success .

what an i missing here ?

Edit: one more thing the led of the 1-GB transceiver is orange not green , plus it is not learning MACs while the 10-GB transceiver led is green and i can see that it is learning MACs.

Comment: According to the manual 'steady yellow' is normal for a SFP+ port with a 1Gbps transceiver module installed.

Answer (score -1):

First, the management interface is intentionally not accessible from the rest of the switch ports. Management interfaces are meant to be plugged into a separate network or VLAN, hence the "out-of-band" title on many of them. You will need to plug directly into the management port, or set up a management subnet to use that port.

As far as the traffic flow, that is a very advanced switch that is going to require more configuration. You will want to look through the manuals here:

http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/manualsResults/?sp4ts.oid=1009148840&spf_p.tpst=psiContentResults&spf_p.prp_psiContentResults=wsrp-navigationalState%3Daction%253Dmanualslist%257Ccontentid%253DSetup-and-install-general%257Clang%253Den&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Here is a manual for the layer two setup to get a basic config working.

http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=1009148840&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c05212329